# How to render react element from a mapped array using object literal to get values

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi do you render a react elements from an array of strings using object literal to get its value? let say for example I got an array of strings and I want to mapped on it using a function that returns an object literal with predefined values, if the strings matched return the react element. Here's what i've tried but doesn't display the icons

```
import { useCallback, useEffect, useMemo } from "react";
import PersonIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Person"
import ShoppingCartIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ShoppingCart'
import SecurityIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Security'
import LocalActivityIcon from '@mui/icons-material/LocalActivity'

export default function App() {

  
  const iconNames = useMemo(()=>['PersonIcon','ShoppingCartIcon', 'SecurityIcon', 'LocalActivityIcon'],[]);
  
  const getIcons = (icon) =>{
    const icons = {
      PersonIcon: <PersonIcon />,
      ShoppingCartIcon: <ShoppingCartIcon />,
      SecurityIcon: <SecurityIcon />,
      LocalActivityIcon: <LocalActivityIcon />
    }
    return icons[icon];
  }

  const displayIcons = useCallback((arr) => {
    return <ul>{arr.map((icon) => { return getIcons[icon] })}</ul>
  },[])

  useEffect(()=>{
    displayIcons(iconNames)
  })

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Icons</h1>
      {displayIcons}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the icons are imported and static, perhaps the `icons` object could be defined outside of the component, so that even without `useMemo` or `useCallback`, it would not be re-created when the component re-renders.

The `getIcons` might not be necessary to access the icons in the object, as in the output JSX, the `icons[name]` can be wrapped in a curly braces `{}` to render the icon.

Example (live demo on: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-lgtoac?file=src/App.js)):

```
import PersonIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Person';
import ShoppingCartIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ShoppingCart';
import SecurityIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Security';
import LocalActivityIcon from '@mui/icons-material/LocalActivity';

//  Can be defined here if the icons are imported and static
const icons = {
  PersonIcon: <PersonIcon />,
  ShoppingCartIcon: <ShoppingCartIcon />,
  SecurityIcon: <SecurityIcon />,
  LocalActivityIcon: <LocalActivityIcon />,
};

//  Just an array of the icon names for testing
const iconNames = Object.keys(icons);

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Icons</h1>
      <ul>
        {iconNames.map((name, index) => (
          <li key={index}>{icons[name]}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

However depending on the use case, perhaps also consider to use other approaches instead of accessing it from an object to display a list of icons.

The example below displays a list of icons, and could also pass the MUI props to style it if needed (may not work for other libraries).

Example (live demo on: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-nvmwlz?file=src/App.js)):

```
// Works for MUI icons but might not for other libraries

const icons = [PersonIcon, ShoppingCartIcon, SecurityIcon, LocalActivityIcon];

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Icons</h1>
      <ul>
        {icons.map((Icon, index) => (
          <li key={index}>
            <Icon fontSize="large" color="primary" />
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Just another possible approach that also works (with MUI) and accepts props for the icons, by defining the icon as component inside `map`:

Example (live demo on: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-yevpzg?file=src/App.js)):

```
// Works for MUI icons but might not for other libraries

const icons = { PersonIcon, ShoppingCartIcon, SecurityIcon, LocalActivityIcon };

const iconNames = Object.keys(icons);

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Icons</h1>
      <ul>
        {iconNames.map((icon, index) => {
          const Icon = icons[icon];
          return (
            <li key={index}>
              <Icon fontSize="large" color="primary" />
            </li>
          );
        })}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: i like your second solution but what if the array you are mapping is an array of object and it has an icon property, how do you implement this

 {icons.map((Icon, index) => (
          <li key={index}>
            <Icon fontSize="large" color="primary" />
          </li>
        ))}

Comment: @Twirlman Perhaps try take the icon out in `map` before `return` as in the last solution, but it would also be depending on the structure of the data and the actual use case indeed.

Answer (score 0):

1. You are calling displayIcons as a variable while this is a function.
2. getIcons is a function not an array. You should do getIcons(icon)

Your code can be reduce to this

```js
import { useCallback, useEffect, useMemo } from "react";
import PersonIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Person"
import ShoppingCartIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ShoppingCart'
import SecurityIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Security'
import LocalActivityIcon from '@mui/icons-material/LocalActivity'

export default function App() {
  const iconNames = ['PersonIcon','ShoppingCartIcon', 'SecurityIcon', 'LocalActivityIcon']
  
  const getIcons = (icon) => {
    const icons = {
      PersonIcon: <PersonIcon />,
      ShoppingCartIcon: <ShoppingCartIcon />,
      SecurityIcon: <SecurityIcon />,
      LocalActivityIcon: <LocalActivityIcon />
    }
    return icons[icon];
  }

  const displayIcons = useCallback(() => {
    return (
      <ul>{iconNames.map((icon) => { return getIcons(icon) })}</ul>
    )
  },[iconNames])

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Icons</h1>
      {displayIcons()}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: yes getIcons is a function, i used to select icons from the object literal. Please check https://codesandbox.io/s/object-literal-mapped-test-lrep3e